# How to query for one value in picklist

Tags: soql

I want to query from one MultiPicklist called Access level. In Access level values are one,two,three,four. few records can have more that one Access level. I want to fetch records which contain Access level is One.
For ex: Access Level : one,two.   this record also i need to fetch based on 'one' value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hi i had already facing this issue.if you want to retrieve values from multiple select list.you must use includes keyword. For example:

```
SELECT Case_Item__c FROM Case where Case_Item__c INCLUDES ('one')
```

The above query will retrieve all records with one in field value and one with two in multi select pick list. But sometimes it will display one with other values. Write two queries one for retrieve all records with value one. Other one for retrieve specific one with two.

Answer (score 0):

```
list <SObject__c> lObjs = [select id, name from Sobject__c where Access_Level__c = 'One'];
```

Comment: Sorry forgot to tell. That is multi picklist. In some records it is having more than one value. So i need to fetch records which contain one.

Comment: There is [documentation on querying multi-select picklists](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_querying_multiselect_picklists.htm). In this case, using `INCLUDES('One')` should accomplish what you want.